How to use environment variables in parameter context of Apache NiFi?
I am working with Apache NiFi and I need to configure parameters dynamically based on environment variables. I understand that NiFi has a parameter context feature, but I am not sure how to directly reference environment variables within this context.
I have several environment variables set on the system where NiFi is running. I need to use these environment variables within my NiFi dataflows, particularly within the parameter context.
I have tried searching through the NiFi documentation and various forums, but haven't found a clear solution.

There is no way to reference environment variables directly in the parameter context.
However, we have below options:
Direct Reference:
We can directly use environment variables in the processor using ${VAR_NAME}
Parameter Provider: We need to use Apache NIFI Parameter provider
Steps to create parameter context using parameter provider
1.We can create parameter provider by NIFI->controller settings->parameter providers-> + ->EnvironmentVariableParameterProvider

Select 'Parameter Group Name'. This will be the name of your parameter context

Select 'Environment Variable Inclusion Strategy' as include All


4.Click on Apply
5.Now you will see three option on parameter provider list item- edit, fetch parameters, delete

The fetch parameters option will fetch all environment variables from the system, and then it will ask to check sensitive parameters.

Then it creates a new parameter context.


Also, We can create multiple environments and use them in existing parameter contexts by using inheritance.
The target parameter will reference the parent parameter context automatically.
Also, as parent parameters are referenced and not copied; the change in the parent does not require a change in the child. Hence the values are always up-to-date
